# Program does not respond to a modal window

Tags: primefaces

I open a modal window when I click a button:

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="mr" title="#{msg.edit_book}" rendered="#{sec:areAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')}" onclick="dlgEditBook.show();">
    <p class="edit">#{msg.edit}</p>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{b}"  target="#{bookDAOImpl.selectedBook}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

A modal window is opened, but the program does not respond to any place there:

```
<p:dialog id="editDialog" modal="true" widgetVar="dlgEditBook" dynamic="true" resizable="false" header="#{msg.edit_book}" closable="false">
    <h:form id="formEditBook">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="col1, col2" styleClass="edit_book_table" >
            <p:panel id="imagePanel">
                <p:graphicImage  value="#{imageController.defaultImage}" width="110" height="150" id="bookImage"/>
            </p:panel>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

`imageController.defaultImage` doesn't work, checked the debugger, it will not be carrying out.

Comment: try to add appendTo="@(body)" to the dialog

Comment: It doesn't work (